# Use a jni shared library in C/C++

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface

I have a closed shared library (armeabi) which is generated under jni (using ndk more precisely). Is it possible for any C/C++ code to use the function of this library? (under android compilation environment). Thanks.

vivian